# CSS - keep scroll position at end of content while expanding

Tags: css

If I have a dynamically expanding block of content and a user has scrolled all the way to the end, is there a pure CSS solution to keep the user at the end when the content expands, appearing to push the content element's siblings upward?

I tried setting `position: sticky, bottom: 0` on the element, but then it is taken out of the document flow and its siblings are overlapping.

Comment: Can you replicate what you have so far in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to change the position of the viewport with pure CSS, which is what you need to do to achieve the effect you're describing. You'll need to use javascript.